# Subjunctive "be" inversion

Tags: grammaticality, semantics, subjunctive-mood, subject-verb-inversion, grammatical-roles

Can i invert the protasis bellow :

> If you not be, ...

Into :

> Be you not, ...

Will it not —in an archaic sense— be mistaken for imperative and will it convey the same conditional notion?

Comment: By ' -- in an archaic sense --' do you mean 'by those with an appreciation of archaisms in the correct setting'? Because to the vast majority of native speakers nowadays, these would both sound outlandish.

Comment: Neither of the examples make much sense with the comma at that point. Your question, as it stands lacks the detail and context to make it clear. It would help to have a full sentence.

Comment: @Greybeard I would imagine it would have to follow a sentence like "it is best if you are prepared."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usage at one point existed in English but now mostly survives in fossilized phrases like "be that as it may" or "if need be."  So I think you are not incorrect to say that if you are specifically aiming to write archaic English it is not wrong to use.

But  to the second part of your question, yes, I do think this is likely to be mistaken for the imperative, because many, if not most, people are not familiar with this construction outside of the fossilized examples.  You will have to judge how erudite your readership is before deciding whether to risk that.

Comment: Just pointing out that "Be that as it may" demonstrates inversion (constructed without *if* or *whether*), but "if need be" does not.

Answer (score 2):

We sometimes still do see this inversion with *be*. For example, to emphasize that there are two or more (usually exhaustive) possibilities or distinctions, but they do not change or affect the point being made:

> Therefore, for every ten Peregrines colour-ringed, at least one is
> likely to be resighted, **be it dead or alive**. [Ed Drewitt; *Urban
> Perigrines*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Urban_Peregrines/6g31CAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22be%20it%20dead%20or%20alive%22&pg=PA126&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> Remember that for all politicians, **be they local, regional or
> national**, the constituents who vote for them are their number 1
> priority. [David Ashton et al.; *How to be a Nurse or Midwife
> Leader*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_to_be_a_Nurse_or_Midwife_Leader/tzWkDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22be%20they%20local%22) (1974)

> It cannot be ignored that parallel importing rules, **be they for or
> against**, evolved in a world of conventional trading patterns where
> physical goods traditionally passed down a chain of exporters to
> importers to retailers to end users. [Fiona Macmillan; *New Directions
> in Copyright Law, vol. 6*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_Directions_in_Copyright_Law/F-T-MMoRpn4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22be%20they%20for%20or%20against%22&pg=PA128&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> The authority of the community is brought to bear on the offender **be
> he an adult or a juvenile**. [James Morrison; *The Healing of
> America*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Healing_of_America/ugGaDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22be%20he%20an%20adult%22&pg=PT105&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> On this point he apposes Rassers ..., who interprets the marriage
> between the two siblings to be the actual end of the story. **Be they
> married or not**, is however less important than the fact that they
> are reunited in some way at all.  [Lydia Kieven; *Following the Cap-Figure in
> Majapahit Temple Reliefs*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Following_the_Cap_Figure_in_Majapahit_Te/BfKBAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22be%20they%20married%20or%20not%22&pg=PA42&printsec=frontcover)

---

We see this occasionally with the verb *come*: *Come rain or come shine, Come hell or high water, Come what may.*

> You wanted to walk around the city, **come rain come snow come
> sleet**, recording things.  I bought a warmer coat with many ingenious
> pockets. [Jenny Offill; *Dept. of Speculation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dept_of_Speculation/ITC0AAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22come%20snow%20come%22&pg=PT14&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> [Terry Shannon; *Come Summer, Come Winter*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Come_Summer_Come_Winter/CcvlnQEACAAJ?hl=en) (1956)

Comment: But it must be done for effect, because "be+subject" can be replaced with a simple *whether*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, in fact I mentioned that it's an alternative to a *whether* construction, but deleted it. :-)

Comment: That said, none of these just places it at the beginning of the sentence, where it might be mistaken for a command.

Comment: @Casey I've added an example where the construction starts the sentence, but--especially, with an "or"--I doubt these  could be taken as imperatives. "Come rain, come shine, we're prepared" is  a subjective ("Whether rain or shine comes, we're prepared), but IMO it's not far from an imperative: "Let rain or shine come! We're prepared.")

Comment: @DjinTonic Good find.  "Be they married or not is less important" sounds awkward to me, but hey, it appeared in published writing.

Comment: @Casey Yes, it's definitely less common at the start, and it most likely relates to something in the previous sentence, as in this example.

Comment: @DjinTonic I find the nominalization strange mostly.  "Be they married or not, all couples should invest in the stock market" sounds fine.

Comment: @Casey. However, if you are addressing the reader/giving advice, "Be *you* married or not, you should invest in the stock market" would be bizarre. :-) But I agree with you about the example I cited.